# Programmatically create or join a home group

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, networking, workgroup

I am trying to write a utility to walk users through connecting and setting up their network.  One requirement I have is to create or join a home group.  I have been able to find [`IHomeGroupProvider.JoinHomeGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsserversolutions.homegroup.ihomegroupprovider.joinhomegroup.aspx) or [`HomeGroupManager.JoinHomeGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsserversolutions.homegroup.homegroupmanager.joinhomegroup.aspx) but I don't know how to get an instance of `IHomeGroupProvider`.  It looks like its in  `wsshomegroupobjectmodel.dll`, but I am not sure if that is only available in windows server or how to get in there in Windows 7.

I think I need to create an instance of `HomeGroupManager`, but again, I don't know where to get the DLL.

Comment: IHomeGroupProvider is an interface - you can't create an instance of an interface.

Comment: Right, which is why I need to either get an instance of HomeGroupManager, or some factory that gives me back an instance of IHomeGroupProvider

Comment: No factory is going to give you "back an instance of IHomeGroupProvider".  It'll give you back an instance of whatever type it returns you which implements the IHomeGroupProvider interface.  You may think i'm sounding pedantic, but i think it's important to make this distinction to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading it right, I think [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg513958.aspx) says that the 'Windows Server Solutions SDK' is packaged in with the Windows Server 2008 R2 SDK which can be downloaded [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=182502).

Once you've got that installed you should be able to use `HomeGroupManager.JoinHomeGroup` without having to manage a `IHomeGroupProvider` instance.

Comment: Once I got the Windoes Server Solutions SDK, I was able to build and compile fine, but every time I Run it an exception is thrown with the message **Connect**, and an error type of [ProviderNotAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsserversolutions.homegroup.errortype.aspx)

my code looks like this:
HomeGroupManager manager = new HomeGroupManager();
string user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
manager.CreateHomeGroup(user);

I checked to make sure the HomeGroupProvider service is running on my machine and everything looks good there.

Comment: I've never used the API, and I cannot seem to find any real examples online yet. Questions like this probably would be better answered on the MSDN forums.